# Crop Video file using UIImagePickerViewController in ios

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

i want to crop video that select from photo Library.Now i can choose Video and get Crop Video File and show cropped movie. 
My problem is that the slider that moves the video with it, moves from right to left, but it's not possible to move from the left to right. there is an screenShot from editor bar.

i can't change yellow slider position from right to left. how can solved this issue?
thanks for all reply.

[image]

Comment: This is the UIImagePickerController default behaviour.Please check another third party libraries to do the same.